# Vertices in Unity In Compare With 3dsMAx

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3dsmax, vertices

I have a tree with 193 vertices in 3dsMax. when I import it in unity it says that my model have 732 vertices.

I write this code for testing coordinates of my testing model.

```
Mesh m;
 m =  GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
        foreach (Vector3 item in m.vertices)
        {
            Debug.Log(item);
        }
```

but with seeing the coordinates in the console window of unity I see some vertices calculate multiple time.
why unity do this?
I think It's awful for performance in Big Scale.

Comment: Are you sure it has just 193 vertices in Max? Try and import the fbx into another 3d software like Blender and see what it shows  there.

Comment: One thing to look for is if you have a modifier in Max like weld vertices and you export without applying it.

Comment: If you break the normals, vertex will be divided. 1 normal corresponds to 1 vertex.

Comment: in another 3d software I have the same vertices count. and we don't merge two model that weld vertices effect the result. do you have the same vertices count in two software?

Comment: shingo i don't get it properly. do you think multiple normal exist for each of vertices and because of this we have more vertices?

Comment: As @shingo suggests graphics engines will always render hard edges as many times as there joining faces / normals / different materials. e.g. a flat shaded cube with a different material on each face will draw 8 x 4 x 4 x 6 verts. Smooth shading and using a single material will reduce this but you should consider it part of your poly count budget. See https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+vert+count+higher+than+model

Comment: another point is that with my above test some vetices count 29 times and some vertices 23 time and some of them  2 or 3 times . why this numbers don't obey any rules and just like randoms?!!!!!

Comment: thank for your precise view point. I test my model with placing  it in scene in my above test code. but   when i  see the vertice count in mesh i see the same result. 732 vertices...

Comment: 3D modeling software may group normals/tangents with a single vertex, so that you don't have to operate on multiple vertices, but Unity doesn't. Take a look at the description https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html

Comment: thus even in your unity system shows different vertices count than 3dsMax. I want to check is this problem is mine or a general problem. because I'm worry about performance problem through excessive vertices count.

Comment: We've answered this 3 times in the comments. Yes, you should allow for the extra vertex count when considering performance. However, on modern GPUs number of verticies is not so important as other issues like draw calls. It's a big subject, please do some research, there are thousands of articles available online.